# How do I differentiate between users in local wifi network android game

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-wifi, local-network

I have two players, one player as server and the other is connecting to the server before the game start.
Now, I am creating a function to be called at the start of the game where i can give each player an id depending on the connection(server or client).

```
  void setUserIdFromConections(){
      if(isClient())
          id = 2;
      if(isServer())
          id = 1;
}
```

My question is How can I get the type of connection (isClient or isServer) ?

Comment: "Did someone connect to me? if so, i am the server"

Comment: Where can get this information ?